# Remove button from customer admin form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to remove the `Create Order` button from the admin customer edit form and I don't know how to do this via a plugin or an event.
[image]
The button is added from `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit::_construct` and I cannot write a plugin for a protected method.
Is there an event, or a public method that is called after the buttons are added and before the layout is rendered that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After test I think it work with `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\OrderButton and` not `Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit`
it has public function:

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
    $data = [];
    if ($customerId && $this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::create')) {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Create Order'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getCreateOrderUrl()),
            'class' => 'add',
            'sort_order' => 40,
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

you can use plugin is public function

Comment: You are right. I can pluginize that method using `around` plugin and make my method return `null`. This makes the button go away. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to write plugin for class which is configured via UI Component configuration file.

There is a `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` file with array of buttons including Create Order Buton:

```
 <item name="order" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\OrderButton</item>
```

In case this item is removed from an array the form will be rendered without "Create Order" button. In your custom module `customer_form.xml` file has to be prepared.

```
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    ...
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton</item>
        <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
        <item name="invalidateToken" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\InvalidateTokenButton</item>
        <item name="resetPassword" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\ResetPasswordButton</item>
        <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\ResetButton</item>
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
    </item>
    ...
</argument>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works nicely. +1. I still orefer the plugin approach because even if by some miracle someone changes the admin theme, the button is still removed.

Comment: Marius, the OrderButton class should not be instantiated in case you do not want to see the button. With the plugin there are 2 classes will be instantiated to perform the action.

Comment: Hmmm...you have a valid point...i will make up my mind on monday

Comment: not working in magento 2.0.16

Answer (score 4):

You can easily remove one of the buttons added into vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml, declaring a new customer_form.xml file into a custom module with the following path:

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

and the content will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="order" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and ended up solving it a different way. I wrote up a class `NullButton` extending button where `getButtonData()` returns an empty array. Then I used a custom xml layout file to assign this class to the offending button. The original layout xml is still being used but that single button is replaced with nothing.

My use case was for a form from a purchased extension but it should work the same for core magento too.

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/order_export_profile_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="save_and_run" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\NullButton</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
</form>
```

Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\NullButton.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Used as a placeholder for where a button class is expected
 * but not be expressed in the resulting html. To fully
 * remove existing button, set this as the Block.
 */
class NullButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```